# If I want to run an abaqus job (in Linux redhat) with user subroutine on parallel processors, how do I do that?

Tags: abaqus

I work in Abaqus 2017 a lot. I have noticed that when I submit any abaqus job (that does not contain any subroutine!) via parallel processing (aka cpus=4 or 8), it runs just fine!

But, when i submit an abaqus job that contains a user subroutine with it via parallel processing, it won't run at all. It will not abort, or terminate, or do anything. The job will freeze.

The only way to run an abaqus job that has a user subroutine with it, is to run the job with single processing. This takes up a lot of time.

I do use the allocatable arrays for the job, and define them in my subroutine. Is there something I should include in my subroutine?

Could you please tell me why is it that the abaqus jobs (with user subroutines) get completely stuck with cpus of 4 and higher? Please?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I'm a bit concerned that this question is venturing too far from Engineering related software (abaqus) and too close to the realm of operating system usage.

Comment: So where should I ask this question? Any help will be appreciated! Please?

Comment: Do your user subroutines interact with the Abaqus API in any way? Or do they just perform operations on top of previously acquired data?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean when you say "Abaqus API"? Also, my user subroutine can be as simple as a uvarm (where all I am doing is getting a variable via getvrm and priniting it to a file), and the job still just freezes midway!!!

Comment: stackoverflow.com may be more appropriate for this. You'll need to show the code though. BTW "printing to a file" sends a red flag to me, how to you manage your parallel processes doing i/o at the same time?

Comment: okay, I will repost this in stack overflow. But, are you suggesting that if I contain code that utilizes writing to a text file, mpi cannot be used?

Comment: @MousumiG yes that is kindof the problem with multithreading. You can only do certain things inside threads efficiently. If you dont obey the rules then you have destroyed the entire threading model.

Comment: you may want to review the user subroutine manual: 2.1.4 OBTAINING PARALLEL PROCESSES INFORMATION