# Does anyone know how would one use "mutexes" in fortran user subroutine so that I can run abaqus job via parallel processing?

Tags: abaqus

I really would like to run my abaqus jobs (that have user subroutines attached to them) very quickly. I have read some sections in documentation about calling a utility subroutine called "MutexInit". I didin't understand when i could use it so that there will be no errors!!!

Could anyone please direct me to anywhere where I can have an idea of what to type in my subroutine files so that I can use cpus 4 or higher to run my abaqus jobs super fast?

Please and thank you very mch!

Comment: Since the comments in this question suggested Stack Overflow - why not post there? https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/21457/10902

Comment: Do you understand what a mutex is in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

you should use include file

```
#include <SMAAspUserSubroutines.hdr>
```

initialize Mutex #1 at begin of the subrotine after include vaba.....
call MutexInit( 1 )

use " call MutexLock( 1 ) "

your program documentation to use for 4 cpus

at the end of

use " call MutexUnlock( 1 ) "

Answer (score -1):

If you are using CAE then you can specifiy the number of CPUs or GPUs in the Job Manger, when creating a job click the Parallelization tab.

You can also do it from the command line `abaqus job=myJob cpus=4`

But how successful you will be depends on your Abaqus license and how many tokens you can use. It will throw an error if you dont have enough tokens or the wrong type of license.

It cant be done just from the usermat. The usermat is compiled into the solver it cant just spawn new threads because the solver is locked to only use a certain number of cores. So unless you have a license to unlock that it cant be done.

In addition when executing the job the number of cores needs to be explicitly declared. If you ask for 4 cores Abaqus will split the whole analysis across 4 cores. If you then try & spawn more cores from your usermat it will throw an error. Sorry but there is no way around this using Abaqus.

Comment: can somebody explain why this was down voted?

Comment: Probably because it does not answer the question which is how to make subroutines parallelizible via using mutex init. If you just take a random subroutine that needs to do side effect code then you need to make sure your code talks in a specific way or abacus just makes it single threaded no matter what your settings.

Comment: and as I explained you can not do that via the usermat & it is down to what Abaqus license you have as to what kind of parallelization you are allowed.

Comment: Yes that but if you read the other questions of the op that is clearly not the problem but rather parallelisizing the  users subroutine, because he says that without it he paralelisizes fine.

Comment: yeah you cant do it unless you have the license to do it. The usermat is compiled into the solver it cant just spawn new threads because the solver is locked only use a certain number of cores. So unless you have a license to unlock that it cant be done.

Comment: yes thats given but does not seem to be the problem. In eitrher case you need to address the question about mutexes, even if explaining how they dont matter preferably with some code that demonstrates this.

Comment: I'm confused, that is the reason why you cant do it. I'll edit my response to reflect these comments but it does seem that people are a bit too trigger happy on this board.

Comment: That is one reason, sure, it is far form the only reason! Anyway this is engineering your supposed to back up your answer somehow if requested. But i find its okay if you just mention that this is the most likely reason

Comment: Anyway you may want to read this: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21457/if-i-want-to-run-an-abaqus-job-in-linux-redhat-with-user-subroutine-on-paralle Which seems to indicate the user knows this